# How do I show a <div> when two radio buttons are selected using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a div which needs to show only when both the radio buttons have been selected. Currently it shows even when only the 2nd radio button is selected.

```
<label>Salaried</label>
<input class="filter1" type="radio" name="occupation" value="salaried" />
<label>Self</label>
<input class="filter1" type="radio" name="occupation" value="self" />

<label>Singlelabel>
<input class="filter2" type="radio" name="status" value="single" />
<label>Married</label>
<input class="filter2" type="radio" name="status" value="married" />

<div style="display: none;">Show only when two radio buttons are selected</div>
```

My jQuery code is below

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("input[name=occupation]"&&"input[name=marital]").click(function () {
      if($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $('div').show();
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't see where this name is: input[name=marital], try changing it to status maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the selector is incorrect. You need to put the separate selectors in a single string, but separate them with a comma. From there you need to verify that both radio inputs have been checked. Your use of `this` only checks the one which was most recently changed. Also note that when dealing with radio and checkbox inputs you should use the `change` event so that your code works for people who navigate using the keyboard as well as the mouse.

Finally, in your HTML example the second radio is named `status` not `marital`, although I assume that's just an error when creating the question.

With all that said, this should work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('input[name="occupation"], input[name="status"]').change(function () {
        if ($('input[name="occupation"]').prop('checked') && $('input[name="status"]').prop('checked')) {
            $('div').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Also note that you can provide a boolean value to `toggle()` to shorten the above code further:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('input[name="occupation"], input[name="status"]').change(function () {
        $('div').toggle($('input[name="occupation"]').prop('checked') && $('input[name="status"]').prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Per the comment from @TrevorHart, there is no input with name="marital".

Comment: Yep, I noticed too. See the second paragraph in my answer.

Comment: I see that but, as a result, your code doesn't work with the OP's HTML.

Answer (score 0):

On every change of the checkboxes check if both are checked.

```
$('input[name="occupation"]').is(":checked") && $('input[name="status"]').is(":checked")
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    if ($('input[name="occupation"]').is(":checked") && $('input[name="status"]').is(":checked")) {
      $('div').show();
    } else {
      $('div').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Salaried</label>
<input class="filter1" type="radio" name="occupation" value="salaried" />
<label>Self</label>
<input class="filter1" type="radio" name="occupation" value="self" />

<label>Singlelabel
  <input class="filter2" type="radio" name="status" value="single" />
  <label>Married</label>
  <input class="filter2" type="radio" name="status" value="married" />

  <div style="display: none;">Show only when two radio buttons are selected</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/gqf2o2mm/5/

#### HTML

```
<label>Salaried</label>
<input class="filter1" type="radio" name="occupation" value="salaried" />
<label>Self</label>
<input class="filter1" type="radio" name="occupation" value="self" />
<label>Single</label>
<input class="filter2" type="radio" name="status" value="single" />
<label>Married</label>
<input class="filter2" type="radio" name="status" value="married" />
<div style="display: none;">Show only when two radio buttons are selected</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="occupation"], input[name="status"]').change(function() {
    if ($('input[name="occupation"]').is(':checked') && $('input[name="status"]').is(':checked')) {
      $('div').show();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest selecting both sets of radio buttons as a single variable by using a [multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).
Then bind a [change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) listener to that selection.

Upon change, determine how many inputs in the selection are checked.
I'm using [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to limit the selection to checked inputs and [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) to count elements in the filtered selection.

I store a boolean value (true or false) to indicate whether the number of checked inputs is two.
This value can be used to define how [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) behaves (show or hide).

```js
var $required_inputs = $('input[name="occupation"], input[name="status"]');

$required_inputs.on('change', function() {
  var two_selected = $required_inputs.filter(':checked').length == 2;
  $('#display').toggle(two_selected);
});
```

```css
#display {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Salaried <input type="radio" name="occupation" value="salaried" /></label>
<label>Self <input type="radio" name="occupation" value="self" /></label>

<label>Single <input type="radio" name="status" value="single" /></label>
<label>Married <input type="radio" name="status" value="married" /></label>

<div id="display">Show only when two radio buttons are selected</div>
```